# Stop thread using return statement

Tags: android, multithreading, return

Stop a thread like:

```
new Thread ( new Runnable() { 

 public void run(){ 
    if ( condition ) return; // this will stop the thread. 

} 
}).start();
```

is correct/safe?

Comment: Yes... it is correct and safe. Didn't you try yourself?

Comment: Yes, I tried and it works, but I was not really sure if this is the best solution...

Comment: It is safe, but this code doesn't make any sense. the run() method will return period. if you are referencing a boolean value inside your thread and depending on it (as in the case of looping until it is met), condition should be synchronized. So while this example will always safely return, the use of condition is not necessarily safe.

Comment: @sethro - It's probably enough to declare `condition` to be volatile if it's a variable being set from another thread. However, there's no indication in OP's question that `condition` is being changed from another thread.

Comment: @sethro, In my case, just this thread can change the `condition` (before the if statement), so I think the synchronization is not needed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thread stops when it's `run()` method returns. It doesn't really matter what logic is used inside `run()` to decide when or how to return. Your code is perfectly correct and safe.

Comment: It can certainly matter what logic is used inside run() to decide when to return. For example, if the logic inside run() was, while(!condition){ // do something } return; run() method may never return even if condition was set to true (on a different thread), unless there was some synchronization on condition.

Comment: @sethro - That doesn't change the fact that the thread stops when the `run()` method returns. It's certainly possible to write infinite loops or run afoul of inter-thread synchronization issues like you describe, but that just means that the `run()` method may never return (and hence the thread will never stop). My answer does need an amendment, however: the thread will stop when the `run()` method _exits_, even if it exits by throwing an exception instead of returning.

Comment: I really don't mean to be pedantic, but the way this question is asked implies that the OP is trying to explicitly stop a `Thread`, which is different than letting a `Thread` complete its task and end. If that's what OP wants to do, then why the condition? Maybe I'm just reading it incorrectly. I am truthfully trying to be helpful as I have seen this kind of asynchronous thread termination many times.

Comment: @sethro - Your point about synchronization is a good one and I wasn't trying to dismiss it. I just wanted to clarify that two different things are being discussed: the rule that a thread exits when the `run()` method returns or abnormally ends (which is a direct answer to OP's question as I understood it) and the rules for correctly sharing data between threads.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> if ( condition ) return; // this will stop the thread.
> ```
>
> is correct/safe?

Certainly. When the thread returns from the `run()` method it will then finish and can be joined with.  The thread would also exit if you threw a `RuntimeException` or just let the code run off the end of the `run()` method obviously without calling `return` specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct and safe...